# Removing white line from bootstrap 3 navbar-inverse dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a as clean as possible menu and have managed to rid it of some unwanted styling. One little white line remains however, and I'm demanding 0 or none for borders all over my CSS, trying to get it gone.

It can be seen in these images above the music icon and below the dropdown icon:
[image: Check it]
[image: With inspection]

It is only in "small screen mode" and with the dropdown active it shows up.

**custom navbar CSS**

```
.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
}

.navbar li { 
 color: white;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.collapse {
border: 0;
}

#myNavbar {
  border: 0;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu::after{
 border:0;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-collapse {
 border: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

**The menu markup:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> Web</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/1GvAs3lGZ6) (press the computer icon to run it in its own window):

How can I point at that element to get him out of there?

Thank you so much for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its a box-shadow just remove/overwrite it

```
.navbar-collapse#myNavbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That was `box-shadow` not a `border` in `.navbar-collapse` class in default bootstrap css. You can overwrite it.

```
.navbar-collapse#myNavbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class in your css.

```
.navbar-collapse {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
overflow-x: visible;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1) !important;
box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1) !important;}
```